# Why are some posts shown with a pink background in the list of flags I've raised?

Tags: support, flagging, deleted-questions

Upon looking under the list of posts I flagged, some are pending/ helpful.  Under those helpful ones, some are highlighted in red. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

If by "highlighted in red" you mean a pink background behind the question title,

> [image]

then that indicates that the post in question has been deleted.

If you mean something else, then you should provide a screenshot and be more descriptive about the circumstances (type of flag raised, whether it was on a question/answer/comment, etc.).

Comment: Yes!  Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @XcoderX The request nevertheless still holds: please be a good deal more specific when using this meta as a help resource.

Comment: Okay noted @EmilioPisanty